# Invalid syntax python on iPhone

Tags: python, iphone, set

I got bored and was trying to install SET from trustedsec GitHub on my old Jailbroken iPhone 4S with iOS 8.4. I was getting an SSL certificate error.

So I used:

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit set/
```

Which I was able to download the package.
Now when I go to install I get an invalid syntax error. I made sure I was in root.

To install I used.

```
iPhone:~ mobile$ cd set
iPhone:~/set mobile$ su
Password:
iPhone:/var/mobile/set root# 
python setup.py install
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. I'm also a newb so be gentle . Sorry don't have enough points to post a picture, and couldn't copy and paste everything the code wasn't lining up properly so it wouldn't let me post the question.

```
File "setup.py", line 10
with
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname
(__file__),
'pexpect', '__int__.py'), 'r') as f:
            ^
Syntax error: invalid syntax
```

[picture of code <===========](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP3Nb.jpg)

Comment: See if you can edit your question now to post the code and error message properly. While I understand that it may be difficult to figure out what Stack Overflow will or won't reject in a question, we do need to see the actual, exact code and error message if we're to help you

Comment: Are you actually on a Python version that this toolkit supports?

Comment: I've added a link a screenshot of the code. Also I'm running python 2.7.3-3

Comment: The error message clearly shows that you're *not* running the Python version you think you are. You're running 2.5. (Also, weird word wrap settings there.)

Comment: Weird I installed 2.7 via cydia.radare.org. I'll try reinstalling it.

Comment: I reinstalled and now I'm getting. /bin/sh: /usr/bin/easy_install: /usr/bin/python 2.5: b ad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: I think you might need a virtualenv to avoid messing with the system-default Python version and things that rely on it. I've never used a virtualenv, though, so I don't know much about them.

Comment: Hey, I uninstalled 2.7 and installed 2.7.8 and now I get -sh /usr/bin/python: bad cpu type in executable any idea what that means?